Hiding subsubsection titles in beamer sidebar
Assume a beamer TeX document that contains

sections
subsections, and
subsubsections

How do I prevent any of the subsubsection titles to be displayed in the Beamer sidebar?
Chapter 10.5 of the beamer user guide does not provide any explanations beyond subsections.
My beamer sidebar information current is as follows:
\useoutertheme[right,width=0.15\paperwidth,hideothersubsections]{sidebar}

MWE:
\documentclass[t,smaller,compress,unknownkeysallowed,handout]{beamer}

\useoutertheme[right,width=0.15\paperwidth,hideothersubsections]{sidebar}

\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}%{sidebar theme}
  {
    \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
    \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
    \vfill
  }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\subsection{Bar}

\subsubsection{Baz}
\begin{frame}{\insertsection}
\begin{block}{\insertsubsection}
\insertsubsubsection\\
This is a slide.\\
I do not want the subsubsection title ('Baz') in the sidebar to the right.\\
How do I get rid of it?  
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Qux}
\begin{frame}{\insertsection}
\begin{block}{\insertsubsection}
\insertsubsubsection\\
This is another slide.\\
I do not want the subsubsection title ('Qux') in the sidebar to the right.\\
How do I get rid of it? 

\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


can you provide a complete minimal example we can compile?

Beamer neither has \subsubsubsection nor \paragraph by default. Consequently they are not shown in the sidebar. Problem solved.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I updated my question - please see the revised version. The issue is not solved!

@cfr A MWE has been added!

You could redefine the subsubsection in sidebar templates to show nothing:
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[right,width=0.15\paperwidth]{sidebar}

\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar}{%
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in sidebar shaded}{%
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}

\subsection{Bar}

\subsubsection{Baz}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection}
\begin{block}{\insertsubsection}
\insertsubsubsection

This is a slide.

I do not want the subsubsection title ('Baz') in the sidebar to the right.

How do I get rid of it?  
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Qux}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\insertsection}
\begin{block}{\insertsubsection}
\insertsubsubsection

This is another slide.

I do not want the subsubsection title ('Qux') in the sidebar to the right.
How do I get rid of it? 

\end{block}
\end{frame}

\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}


